# Draw QGraphicsWidget outside of parent

Tags: python, layout, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm working on a node editor and I'm currently creating my own system using `QGraphicsWidget` and `QGraphicsScene`. I find it very flexible to use a `QGraphicsGridLayout` in my `Node` class and just add sub-components like text/number input, labels etc to the layout. Now, my problem is that I would like to create a socket right next to an input, which should look like a small circle where an edge can be connected. It currently looks like this:

[image: Current look of my system]

However, I can not get the socket to be placed half way outside the Node. I tried painting it in the `paint()` method of my `Node` class, but then it leaves traces from the part that is outside when the node is moved, and I loose some of the flexibility. What's the best way to achieve the below look?

[image: Image of node editor]

Below is my `Node` class and my `Socket` class.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRectF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainterPath, QBrush, QFont, QColor, QPalette
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsTextItem, QGraphicsWidget, QGraphicsGridLayout, QLabel, \
    QLineEdit, QSizePolicy

from src.gui.widgets.graphics.node_scene import NodeScene
from src.gui.widgets.graphics.socket import Socket, SOCKET_TYPE_FLOAT, SOCKET_TYPE_RGB


class Node(QGraphicsWidget):
    def __init__(self, scene: NodeScene, title: str = "", parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # define data properties
        self._input_sockets = []

        # define Node properties
        self._scene = scene
        self._width = 200
        self._height = 200
        self._rounding = 5
        self._padding = 8
        self._bg_color = QColor(80, 80, 100, 200)
        self._title_color = Qt.white
        self._title_font = QFont("Corbel", 8)
        self._title_font.setBold(True)
        self._title = title
        self._title_item = None

        # Define socket properties
        self._socket_label_font = QFont("Corbel", 7)
        self._socket_label_palette = QPalette()
        self._socket_label_palette.setColor(QPalette.Background, QColor(0, 0, 0, 0))
        self._socket_label_palette.setColor(QPalette.Foreground, self._title_color)

        # Define layout
        self._layout = QGraphicsGridLayout()
        self._layout.setColumnAlignment(0, Qt.AlignLeft)
        #self._layout.setContentsMargins(*[self._padding] * 4)
        self._layout.setHorizontalSpacing(2.0)
        self._layout.setRowSpacing(0, 16)
        self.setLayout(self._layout)

        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable, True)

        # Try adding an input
        self.add_input(SOCKET_TYPE_FLOAT, "Test input")

        # Initialize title
        self._create_title()
        self.title = self._title

    @property
    def title(self):
        return self._title

    @title.setter
    def title(self, value):
        self._title = value
        self._title_item.setPlainText(self._title)

    def _create_title(self):
        self._title_item = QGraphicsTextItem(self)
        self._title_item.setDefaultTextColor(self._title_color)
        self._title_item.setFont(self._title_font)
        self._title_item.setPos(self._padding, 0)
        self._title_item.setTextWidth(self._width - self._padding)

    def boundingRect(self) -> QtCore.QRectF:
        return QRectF(0, 0, self._width, self._height).normalized()

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        path_bg = QPainterPath()
        path_bg.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self._width, self._height, self._rounding, 1)
        painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)  # Disables the border
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(self._bg_color))
        painter.drawPath(path_bg)

    def add_input(self, input_type: str, input_name: str, input_range=(0, 1)):
        if input_type == SOCKET_TYPE_FLOAT:
            socket = Socket()
            self._layout.addItem(Socket(), 1, 0)

        if input_type == SOCKET_TYPE_RGB:
            socket = Socket()
            self._layout.addItem(Socket(), 1, 0)
```

And `Socket` class

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRectF, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainterPath, QColor, QBrush
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsWidget

SOCKET_TYPE_FLOAT = "type_float"
SOCKET_TYPE_RGB = "type_rgb"


class Socket(QGraphicsWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

        self._circle_color = QColor(255, 130, 0, 255)
        self._bbox = QRectF(0, 0, 10, 10)
        self._current_edge = None

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self._bbox

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addEllipse(self._bbox)
        painter.setPen(Qt.black)
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(self._circle_color))
        painter.drawPath(path)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to set negative margins for the layout, but you can't use `setContentsMargins()` with negative values, as QGraphicsLayout automatically normalizes margins to 0 if that happens.

The solution I came up with was to subclass the layout and override the `getContentsMargins()` to return negative margins instead:

```
class NegativeMarginsLayout(QGraphicsGridLayout):
    def __init__(self, *margins):
        super().__init__()
        self._margins = margins

    def setContentsMargins(self, *margins):
        self._margins = margins
        self.invalidate()
        self.activate()

    def getContentsMargins(self):
        return self._margins

class Node(QGraphicsWidget):
    def __init__(self, scene: QGraphicsScene, title: str = "", parent=None):
        # ...
        self._layout = NegativeMarginsLayout(-20, 0, 20, 0)
```

[image: layout outside margins]

Note that using a QGraphicsLayout might create problems with collision functions for mouse events, so you should probably override [`shape()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicswidget.html#shape) and return a QPainterPath of the boundingRect (possibly adjusted with the layout margins). Also, you don't need to create a QPainterPath for drawing the shape of the rounded rect, just use `QPainter.drawRoundedRect`.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much!